# How to configure the bootstrap classpath of an Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, bootclasspath

I'd like to replace some of the classes (`javax.tools.*`) of `rt.jar` that my Eclipse plug-in depends on by my own versions of these classes. Replacing the classes in `rt.jar` is typically done by setting the bootclasspath. My question is how to do this in an Eclipse plug-in.

I created a JAR file of my versions of these classes and added it to the `Bundle-ClassPath` attribute of `MANIFEST.MF`, the `bin.includes` attribute of `build.properties`, and `.classpath`. I also entered the path to my JAR file to the field called "Bootstrap entries:" of the Eclipse Application launch configuration dialog and moved my JAR to the top in the "Order and Export" tab at "Project Properties > Build Path". Nonetheless, when I run my Eclipse plug-in using an Eclipse Application launch configuration, the plug-in uses the original classes in `rt.jar` rather than the ones in my JAR file.

How can I configure my Eclipse plug-in so that it first looks up the classes in my JAR file and consults `rt.jar` only if the class is not found in my JAR file?

Comment: Do you need to specifically ONLY override the rt.jar classes for instantiations from your plugin, or do you want override for the application as a whole?

Comment: Currently, just for a single plug-in, although it would be nice to know the answer in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution that I found is to configure the JRE on which the plug-in runs.

To find the JRE on which your plug-in runs, you first need to find the execution environment of your plug-in. Open the `MANIFEST.MF` file of the plug-in and find the execution environment that the `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment` attribute is set to, e.g., `JavaSE-1.6`.

In Eclipse, each execution environment is mapped to a JRE installation. To find the JRE that your execution environment is set to go to `Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Execution Environments` and click on the execution environment used by your plug-in.

You need to configure the JRE on which your plug-in runs. Go to `Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs` and select the JRE used by your plug-in. Press the `Edit...` button and set the `Default VM arguments` to `-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/your/jar.jar`. Finally, click the `Finish` button and then the `OK` button on the preferences window.

You may be able to set the VM arguments in different places, e.g., on the launch configuration dialog of your Eclipse Application.